# Duplicate src packages when importing an existing project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to import an existing project into eclipse, 
I see duplicate packages for src folder(highlighted in red below)
Not sure why.How do i fix this?

[image: src folders highlighted in red]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an issue, actually It's fine.

Eclipse displays the package view (as you pointed in the first red square) and also the directories inside your project (the second square).

As you can see in your screenshot, the first 3 folders contain the package icon (that's because you are using the **Package Explorer** view), then below your Maven dependencies you can find the physical folders.

If you don't want to see your package folder you may consider using **Navigator** view instead of **Package Explorer**.

Btw, you can configure filters for your view by using:

[image]

[image]

Then select the filter you consider appropiated.

Comment: Thanks Navigator view is what I am looking for !

Comment: I am in the same issue, but when I edit in one place the other is not updated. Very weird...